# How to deal with spaces in filenames in batch?

Tags: batch-file, scripting, command, whitespace, filenames

I have a batch file that allows the user to enter a file. It enters and stores the file path correctly. But when I go to enter the file and do anything with it, (in my case just set line1 as the first line and print it), It can't find the filename because it has a space in there.

Here is the code.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /p "infile=enter file"
Echo you're file is %infile%


setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%infile%") do (
set line1= %1
    goto :endfor
)
:endfor
echo %line1%

pause
endlocal
```

And here is what happens.

[image]

When trying to find the file, The system thinks that files name ends at "my" instead of the full "my text.txt" How could I deal with the space in the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not the space in the name of the file. Your problem is that you are typing the name of the file with quotes, quotes that are stored in the variable, and then placing aditional quotes in the `for` command.

```
SET /p "infile=enter file"
set "infile=%infile:"=%"
Echo you're file is %infile%
```

Ensure there are no aditional quotes in the filename and this error will not happen (or don't use quotes when typing the name of the file)

Comment: Wow that is perfect! I can't believe it was that! I thought since it was looking for the "my" in that directory that the space was cutting it short. Never would have guessed that was my issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to MC_ND's answer:
In the original code this line should be set to %%a and not %1 (without the space too):

```
set line1= %1
```

Comment: Yes, that was wrong too. I don't know why, but I had that in another script I wrote, but that script works, so I'm not gonna touch it haha